# application review request

Tags: php, mysql

just coming to the "end" of a project that will probably live for a long time...

Have looked at the FAQ and having not really found a definitive answer, I want to ask if its OK, to kindly ask if it is OK to ask for some thoughts on our system we are about to publish. (wow what a sentence! :)

So, before I post the link, because I don't want to be thought of as a spammer, is it ok?

---

Comment: Are the links in question going to live as long as Stack Overflow? Please consider making some screen shots, adding a bit more regarding functionality and the results you want to achieve, and any other useful information you can think of that would answer questions regarding your question. While I'm not voting to close this, I would recommend that you help 'future proof' this question so that it doesn't become 0XDEADBEEF in the future, at least as far as Stack Overflow is concerned. Doing this will also attract more answers, for we are lazy when it comes to clicking links.

Comment: the point of the question was to gain feedback for a system. I dont think screen shots would really help, other than give you a picture to look at. But, to keep the 'babe alive' I will happily add some.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

This is a programming Q&A site. If you have a question related to programming, you may ask it. If you ask us for a vague review of a candy shop website, you may not ask it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really want a feedback from design/architecture, database schema, performance, reliability perspective, better would be to ask objectively, for instance post your schema, design, etc.

And since you've already developed the web site, this may be a bit late, but its always worthy reading, my fav SO question: [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site) This covers 360 degrees of whats and hows of building a website.